# How can an equidistance, spherical panorama image be generated from Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera, world, hdri

I'd like to use Blender cycles to generate an image which can be used as a world background image. An example is this kind of image is from [hrdmaps.com](http://hdrmaps.com/freebies/road-in-valley)
[image]

How can a blender scene be rendered like this?

Comment: Have you looked into the panoramic cameras settings under *Properties Window > Object Data (camera) > Lens > Panoramic* ?

Comment: Which render engine are you using?

Comment: I want to do this in cycles. The question was updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is natively supported in Cycles.

- Set your output resolution at a 2x1 ratio (e.g. 2048x1024).
- Select the camera.
- In the properties window, camera tab, select "Panoramic."
- For "Type" select Equirectangular.

Here's what it looks like for me:

[image]