# Make a spherical background image

Tags: rendering

How do I make a spherical background image from a Blender model, for example a city at night, rendered onto the inside of a sphere for use as a background?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a skybox? It gives you the same result http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs424/notes2013/webgl/skybox-and-reflection/skybox.html and is easier to setup.

Comment: This can be achieved with a Cycles equirectangular camera. I'm on a phone now—will post more info when I get to a real computer if this question is still open.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the question asked here: [How can an equidistance, spherical panorama image be generated from Blender Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63177/how-can-an-equidistance-spherical-panorama-image-be-generated-from-blender-cycl/63186#63186) See the answer for information on setting up a Cycles-based equirectangular camera.

As Leander mentioned: If you prefer to use Blender Internal or the Blender Game Engine, a Skybox is probably your best bet (simply render six 90º FOV square images, then make a cube out of the results and use that to surround your scene.