# Cycles render reuse sky

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have created a set with night sky, stars and moons, clouds, etc.. Stars are basically particle system used inside a big sphere (which is my night sky basically) and moon, clouds are all separate objects. I use a moving camera inside the scene for my animation. I was wondering if there is a way for me to render my full night sky with moon and clouds and use it as a image material for the sphere instead of rendering each frame which takes forever?

Comment: There are probably a couple of good methods for achieving what you want. One relatively easy method would be to move every object in your scene except the night sky objects to a new layer, then create a spherical panorama of only the night sky (as detailed here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/63177/15132). Then you would add that panoramic render back in as a HDRI environment texture. Although probably not the fastest method, it will render significantly quicker as cycles does not have to compute excessive geometry from the particle systems, etc.

Comment: @Hexbob6 i think this should be an Answer. Otherwise this question will never get closed.

Comment: @J.Doe yes, wasn't sure if it was technically a duplicate question as my method linked to a question that had been answered elsewhere. Will add a bit more detail and convert it to an answer later... :)

Comment: Hi all, yes, using the panaromic with render to hdri texture image worked perfect. Thanks a lot!